# python3-rencode & python3-setproctitle it is not installable

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dependencies, python3

I'm trying to upgrade deluge-common but keep getting this error, i try to google but cannot find the answer.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 deluge-common : Depends: python3-rencode but it is not installable
                 Depends: python3-setproctitle but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 and want upgrade to 18.04 but stuck at this error.

Thanks

Comment: "Not installable" means not available in any repository. Probably you need to enable `universe` (look it up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned by fkraiem, you can either enable "universe" in your source repository by doing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now, you can retry the upgrade

Or you can also directly download them here:
https://pkgs.org/download/python3-rencode and
https://pkgs.org/download/python3-setproctitle
(select those corresponding to your version of Ubuntu, installed them and try to upgrade.

NB: My personal opinion is when you are upgrading your version of Ubuntu, it usually better to make a fresh installation as a lot of packages are changed (some are no longer maintained and others are newly created like your python packages).

Comment: It is a very bad idea to install packages as stand-alone DEBs, since then you don't get automatic updates.

Comment: I agree that's not the perfect solution (as I said, I preferred fresh installation) but once the upgrade will be done to 18.04, both packages are in the repository so they should be updated automatically.